# Named page-router-outlet adds blue header on top of the app

Tags: angular, navigation, nativescript, router

I am using nativescript and Angular and trying to implement tabs. Everything is good however i get blue line with word 'client' on top of the app. It comes from page-router-outlet. I know it sounds crazy but i do not have any items with word 'client' in my app keeping in mind that i just started and copied bottom navigation from example. I will attach screenshot in order to visualize it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It must be name of your app. By default the Actionbar (the blue bar) might show the name of your app. You may get rid of the ActionBar from `page-router-outlet` by setting `actionBarVisibility` attribute to `never`

```
<page-router-outlet actionBarVisibility="never"></page-router-outlet>
```